# Unable to insert data into MYSQL due to UTC

Tags: mysql, timestamp, fullcalendar

I am trying to use FullCalendar v4 and cannot post data to MySQL. I have narrowed the problem down to $start and $end having UTC on the end and MySQL won't take it even though my datatype is TIMESTAMP.  If I manually assign standard datetime data (without UTC) to $start and $end it will post to table. I have the statements commented out in the event.php that work, by overriding the data in the $POST.

My thought is I have something askew in MySQL that is causing the TIMESTAMP datatype to actually be a DATETIME datatype. I have deleted and created the table with SQL Statement shown below.

Running -> MySQL 8.01.5, Windows Server 2016, PHP 7.2.7, using jQuery

...
    CREATE TABLE calendarsystem.events (

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

title VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

end TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

resourceId VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
```

...

The code to add_event.php:

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$resourceId = $_POST['resourceId'];

//$title = 'wtf';

//$start = '2019-03-25 16:00:00';

//$end = '2019-03-25T17:00:00';

//$resourceId = 'b';

try {
    require "db_config.php";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (title, start, end, resourceId) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :resourceId )";

$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);

   q->execute(array(':title'=>$title,':start'=>$start,':end'=>$end,':resourceId'=>$resourceId));
?>
```

...

If I open MySQL Workbench and try to add the data with the UTC copied from the output window of chrome I get the following error when applying:

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
INSERT INTO `calendarsystem`.`events` (`start`, `end`, `title`, `resourceId`) VALUES ('2019-03-25T14:00:00-05:00', '2019-03-25T15:00:00-05:00', 'xxx', 'b');

ERROR 1292: 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-25T14:00:00-05:00' for column 'start' at row 1
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `calendarsystem`.`events` (`start`, `end`, `title`, `resourceId`) VALUES ('2019-03-25T14:00:00-05:00', '2019-03-25T15:00:00-05:00', 'xxx', 'b')

Sorry the post formatting is crappy

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL isn't recognizing the '`T`' character or the trailing time offset in the string value.

```
 '2019-03-25T15:00:00-05:00'
            ^        ^^^^^^
```

One way to fix the problem would be to remove that `T` character and the offset

```
 '2019-03-25 15:00:00'
            ^
```

We expect MySQL to recognize a string in that format.

Alternatively, we could use `STR_TO_DATE` function with appropriate format model so MySQL can interpret datetime/timestamp values from strings in different formats.

The relevant topic in the MySQL Referenced Manual is here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: Tried that, it still fails with or without the T in it when attempting to post manually into workbench...

Comment: My answer highlighted the time zone offset `'-05:00'` at the end string as a problem.  (That's a time zone offset, not "UTC at the end".)